# Rhino: how to protect object fields from being modified?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am using Rhino in Java and in my javascript I change some Java object's fields without a problem, although I initialize scope with initSafeStandardObjects() (and after I add some stuff to the scope, I call scope.sealObject()). My question is this: how can I ensure that Java objects that my javascript access don't get modified by the javascript code?

Example code (simplified):

```
Context cx = Context.enter();
cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
sharedScope = cx.initSafeStandardObjects(new ImporterTopLevel(cx, true), true);
cx.evaluateString(sharedScope, "function log(text) { if (DEBUG) com.betalord.sgx.core.Misc.log(\"[JSBOT] \" + text); }", "init", 1, null);

String additionalImports = 
"importClass(Packages.com.betalord.sgx.core.Misc);" +
"importClass(Packages.com.betalord.sgx.core.Definitions);" +
"importClass(Packages.com.betalord.sgx.bots.BotUtils);" +
"importClass(Packages.com.betalord.sgx.core.GameState);";
cx.evaluateString(sharedScope , additionalImports, "additional imports", 1, null);

String loadMe = "RegExp; getClass; java; Packages; JavaAdapter;";
cx.evaluateString(sharedScope , loadMe, "lazyLoad", 1, null);
sharedScope.sealObject();
cx.seal(null);
Context.exit();
```

Later on, when I create a Bot class, I create an instance scope:

```
Scriptable scope = cx.newObject(sharedScope);
scope.setPrototype(sharedScope);
scope.setParentScope(null);
```

I then get Function from the javascript and call it like `fnTick.call(cx, scope, scope, new String[]{});`

And the javascript code is this (the part that does the calls that should not be allowed):

```
var myBest = BotUtils.getPlanetWithMostShips(mine);

myBest.ships++; // This works, but it shouldn't. It should raise an exception when trying to modify Planet's field "ships".

// Also the code bellow works, although it shouldn't (it's reflection):
var field = myBest.getClass().getDeclaredField("prod");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(myBest, new java.lang.Integer(30));
```

So, how can I prevent javascript code from modifying my Java objects? How can I prevent it from using reflection (the getClass() method, for example)?